# Roll a fair die and denote the outcome by $Y$ . Then flip $Y$ fair coins and let $X$ denote the number of tails observed.

Tags: probability, random-variables

> Roll a fair die and denote the outcome by $Y$. Then flip $Y$ fair coins and let $X$ denote the number of tails observed.
>
> 1. Find the probability mass function of $X$
> 2. Compute the expectation of $X$

**My Attempt**

The number of possible combinations of $y$ coins is $2^y$  and the number of combinations with $x$ tails is $\binom{y}{x}$. Thus, the probabilities are $p_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{\binom{y}{x}}{2^y}$. Then the joint p.m.f. is

\begin{array}{c|c|ccc}
& & & & Y & & & \\ \hline
& & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline
& 1 & 1/2 &\ 1/2 & 3/8 & 1/4 & 5/32 & 3/32 \\ 
& 2 & 0 & 1/4 & 3/8 & 3/8 & 5/16 & 15/64 \\ 
X& 3 & 0 & 0 & 1/8 & 1/4 & 5/16 & 5/16 \\ 
& 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/16 & 5/32 & 15/64\\ 
& 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/32 & 3/32\\ 
& 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/64\\ 
\end{array}

This is my thinking but I know that it is wrong because the sum of all the probabilities exceeds $1$. Can I get some pointers on where I went wrong?

After I find the joint p.m.f., I can sum the values in the rows to find the p.m.f. for $X$.

Comment: Two things: $X$ can be zero and you should divide each element by $1/6$ because that's the probability that $Y$ is equal to any value. So after adding the row zero it all should sum $6$, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Y represents the outcome of a fair die and X represents the number of tails observed then,

$ \ 0 \leq x \leq y$ and $1 \leq y \leq 6 \ $

$ \displaystyle P(X = x|Y=y) = {y \choose x} \cdot \frac{1}{2^y}$

So the table that you have put together is correct but you missed $x = 0$, probability of which is same as for $x = y$.

Edit:

To find pmf of X,

$ \displaystyle P(X = x) = \frac{1}{6} \sum \limits_{y=1}^6 P(X = x|Y=y) \ \ (0 \leq x \leq 6)$

To find expectation of X,

$\mathbb{E}(X) = \sum \limits_{x=0}^6 x \cdot P(X = x)$

Comment: Also on your question of probability adding to more than $1$, comments of Anilch says it. Each outcome of die $(Y = y)$ has a probability of $\frac{1}{6}$. So sum of each column needs to be multiplied by $\frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: Why would the probability that $x=0$ be the same as $x=6$? Using the formula, it would be $1/2,1/4,1/8,1/16,1/32,1/64$. Then it will all sum to $6$

Comment: sorry I wanted to write $x = y$

Comment: so when $y = 1, P(X = 0) = P(X = 1)$, when $y = 2, P(X = 0) = P(X = 2)$, when $y = 3, P(X = 0) = P(X = 3)$ and so on... that is because probability of zero tails is same as probability of zero heads.

Comment: Also the expectation can be found by Law of Total Expectation: $\mathsf E(X)=\mathsf E\big(\mathsf E(X\mid Y)\big)$, which can be evaluated since $X\,{\mid}\,Y\sim\mathcal{Bin}(Y,1/2)$, and $Y\sim\mathcal{U}\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and these distribution families have well known formula for expectation.  @JamesAnderson